# Eigenvalues and Determinants of Two Matricies

Tags: matrices, determinant, matrix-equations, matrix-decomposition, matrix-rank

Suppose $B=[v,e]$ is an $n \times 2$ matrix with $v=[v_1,...,v_n]^T$ and $e=[1,...,1]^T$, and $J_{2\times 2}=[(0,1),(1,0)]$, and so $Rank(BJB^T)=2$.  How can we prove that $BJB^T$ and $JB^TB$ have the same non-zero eigenvalues? Also, how can we prove that 
$$det(I-BJB^T)=det(I-JB^TB)$$

Thank you!

Comment: You can use [Sylvester's determinant theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_determinant_theorem).

Comment: Thank you!  This is helpful.  Just add one relevant link for the determinant of a block matrix: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/898151/block-matrix-determinant