# In block-diagonal computation of the determinant, do the block sizes need to be equal?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For a block-diagonal matrix with, for simplicity, blocks of sizes 4,3,2, I would like to claim that the determinant of this matrix is just the det(4x4 block)*det(3x3 block)*det(2x2 block), basically thinking of the blocks as scalars instead.  Is this claim true?

Perhaps it is not true, because the result, det(AB) = det(A)det(B), would force the block sizes to be equal.

But, I wonder whether there is a more general result that does not force the blocks sizes to be equal.

Thanks,

Comment: That is exact. Just think of blocks as elements of *rings* of matrices. Matrices are not only defined on $\mathbf R$ or $\mathbf C$.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Block matrix determinant](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/898151/block-matrix-determinant)

Comment: Hi @Bernard -- did you also mean to agree with the claim about the computation of the determinant?  muaddib's link brings up something new for me to consider: I feel that my claim about the computation of the determinant is true, but on the other hand, the result det(AB) = det(A)det(B) would force the blocks to have equal size.  Or, did you just mean to agree with the block-diagonal matrix multiplication being equivalent to ordinary diagonal matrix multiplication, e.g., just simply multiply the corresponding diagonal entries to get my new matrix?  Thanks,

Comment: HI @Bernard, I just read a little further down on that link and saw that Sami gives a more general result that doesn't force the block sizes to be equal, I think.  But feel free to comment further, if have something more to add.  Thanks for your time :-)

Comment: Hi @muaddib, thanks so much for the link :-)

Comment: Hi @Bernard, actually, I can't say for sure whether that proof holds for blocks of different sizes, so I have edited my question just now to ask specifically about this.  Thanks,

Comment: It's all true, and based on the extension of Laplace expansion to the devzlopment of a  determinant along a *group* of columns or rows.

Comment: Ok, got it - thanks for your time, @Bernard :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We want to show that 
$$\det\pmatrix{A&0&0\\0&B&0\\0&0&C}\; = \det(A)det(B)\det(C)$$
where $A,B,C$ are square matrices but of not necessarily the same dimensions.

We can use the result in [Block Matrix Determinant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/898151/block-matrix-determinant) to proof the result "inductively".  There it is shown that 
$$\det\pmatrix{A&0\\0&D}\; = \det(A)det(D)$$

We can fit this problem into that one by letting
$$D = \pmatrix{B&0\\0&C}$$

But also by that problem
$$\det\pmatrix{B&0\\0&C}\; = \det(B)det(C)$$

So $$\det\pmatrix{A&0&0\\0&B&0\\0&0&C}\; = \det(A)det(D) = \det(A)\det(B)\det(C)$$

Comment: Very pretty, @muaddib -- so isn't it strange that it violates the result det(AB) = det(A)det(B)?  The left-hand term of this result does not make sense for matrices of different sizes.  Unless the result is based on the assumption that matrix (block) sizes are equal to begin with.

Comment: @LebronJames  I personally don't find it strange.  This result is more about how the determinant acts on direct sums of vector spaces.  If the matrix is $0$ on the off diagonals then the three vector spaces acted on by $A, B, C$ are "independent" and the determinant's effect is to just "multiply" together.

Comment: Ah, very cool intuition, @muaddib.  I also just found the result on Wiki, which certainly assumes first that the matrix sizes are equal, before stating the result det(AB) = det(A)*det(B).  So, this result is irrelevant to the generalized result that you gave and proved.  Thanks for your helpful answer and comments.  Have a great night :-)

Comment: @LebronJames  Happy it helped.  You have a great night as well sir.

Comment: Hi @muaddib, can I squeeze in an annoying question, if you don't mind?  Is a 1x1 block trivially upper-triangular and diagonal?  I'm working on induction proofs and would like to claim this is true for the case n=1. Thanks,

Comment: @LebronJames - I think that is fine.  The base case is usually somewhat "trivial".  But I would be a bit wary if you relied on that specification too much.  You might just be playing around with definitions.  If you want to be totally sure, you can start with $n=2$ to avoid the ambiguity.

Comment: Ok, got it - thanks so much @muaddib :-)