# how to show a matrix is totally unimodular, 1-sum property

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, total-unimodularity

If $A, B \in \{0, 1, −1\}m×n$ are totally unimodular $(TU)$ matrices,
then show that the matrix

\begin{bmatrix}
A&0\\
0&B\end{bmatrix}

is also $TU$, where $O \in \{0\}$
m×n
is an all $0$’s matrix.

I am trying to solve the above problem, but I'm not sure how one proves a matrix is $TU$. I've seen a few proofs online that involve induction with certain property assumptions about the matrix but I'm not sure how to apply this here. It is easy to see that [$A$ $0$] and [$0$ $B$] are $TU$ because you will always have a column of $0$s and that gives you a determinant of $0$ or you have a submatrix of $A$ or $B$ and that itself is $TU$ but I'm not sure how to proceed from there. Is there a general way I can show a matrix is unimodular, and how can i show this final matrix is $TU$?

Comment: The determinant of the [block matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/898159/121671) in your problem is $\operatorname{det}(A) \cdot \operatorname{det}(B)$

Comment: notice that a square submatrix is either singular or it is composed by two square blocks, one in $A$ and one in $B$

Comment: @OliverDíaz the OP has to prove it is Totally Unimodular, not just Unimodular